# What datatype does linq return?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, linq

I'm trying to write a function that will return all the available cars for rent from a single table `Cars`. `Cars` has `carId`(int), `carManufacturer`(varchar), `carModel`(varchar) and `carTaken`(bool).

But I am having problem with figuring out what datatype should the function `GetAvailableCars()` return.

I want to place all of the cars that are rentable(`carTaken == false`) into a textArea on the web-client's simple page in a formatted way. I though `string[]` would be a good choice.

```
public string[] GetAllAvailableCars()
   {
       var result =
           from car in carsDB.Cars
           where (car.carTaken == false)
           select car;
       return result;
   }
```

Comment: You could find out in the IDE by mousing over 'var' - that will tell you what the datatype is.

Comment: I want to downvote the question as it fully refer to the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return a string array, something like:

```
(from car in carsDB.Cars
 where (car.carTaken == false)
 select car.carModel).ToArray();
```

Should work

EDIT:  Per the request of author, to select all of the columns:

```
(from car in carsDB.Cars
 where (car.carTaken == false)
 select String.Format(
     "ID: {0}; Manufacturer: {1}; Model: {2}",
     car.carId,
     car.carManufacturer,
     car.carModel
 )).ToArray();
```

I can't compile against your Cars class, but I think the above is right.  Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: Be careful to copy-paste, this gives only the model.

Comment: Hmmm. How can you select all of the column from the table? I tried `select car.CarModel, car.` but at this point it finds the statement as an error.

Comment: @Gabriel GM: I know I didn't copy and paste.  Had I selected car, that would not have been a String[].  It would have been a Cars[].  I was trying to demonstrate a String[].

Comment: `car.carTaken ? "Yes" : "No"` gives me `cannot convert bool? to bool`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that (See my updated reply).  It doesn't make sense to show the user the car is not taken when that's a constraint in the where clause.  To fix that error, you would do something like:  `(car.carTaken ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No"` .  `??` is the null-coalescing operator and, in the case of nullable types, it converts them to their non-nullable equivalent, using the value specified after the `??`.  The parenthesis may be redundant; I cannot remember C# precedence regarding nullable and ternary off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `IQueryable<Car>` to me- at least that is what the variable `result` will be.

Answer (score 2):

Query returns data object `Car`. Use this code to get all names:

```
public string[] GetAllAvailableCars()
{
    return carsDB.Cars
       .Where(x => x.carTaken == false) // filter cars
       .Select(car => car.model) // select what we need
       .ToArray(); // Execute query
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
public IQueryable<string> GetAllAvailableCars()
{
    return carsDB.Cars.Where(c => c.carTaken == false).Select(c => c.model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab at this but don't you want to select car.Model, not the whole car?

Comment: Actually I want to select all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ works on `Deferred Execution`.

```
from car in carsDB.Cars
       where (car.carTaken == false)
       select car;
```

It just returns the query. But not the actual results of the query.

You have to fetch the results, by converting it to an Array or list etc.

[Good Starting point is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from car in carsDB.Cars
                         where car.carTaken == false
                         select car;
```

result is an IEnumerable of car

```
var result = (from car in carsDB.Cars
                             where car.carTaken == false
                             select car).ToArray();
```

result is car[]

for specific return such as this:

```
var result = from car in carsDB.Cars
                             where car.carTaken == false
                             select new {car.a, car.b};
```

result is IEnumerable of a,b

Answer (score 0):

There is no single datatype for LINQ queries as it depends on the context.

In your case you are selecting "Car" so the datatype is going to be IQueryable.  As pointed out in the comments you can hold your mouse over any var (not just those involving LINQ queries) to get the datatype.